# Access company computer from home using mobile network

Tags: ssh, remote, openssh, remote-desktop

I would like to achieve the same goal as described here:

[SSH PC at office in local network from home](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168242/186283)

The context is the same except that my home computer doesn't have a public IP (I get connected to the Internet using a shared connection with my phone so I am using mobile connection which doesn't provide a public IP, see [Debian 9 - Fail ping my public IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399657/debian-9-fail-ping-my-public-ip))

Comment: So, do you actually have a question?

Comment: To achieve the same goal as :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168242/186283

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your company's permission / are the person making the rules I would take a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) for making an internal node accessible over the internet.

I've personally never used it but have heard good things regarding its functionality and, having a scan over the documentation, appears to offer SSH tunneling.